# Node v10.23.0 Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, bcrypt

[image: Error Message]

Running node v10.23.0, NPM 6.14.8, Centos7

**/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory**

I tried `npm install bcrypt` - same error.

I tried `npm install bcrypt@^3` - same error.

I tried `npm install bcrypt@3` - same error.

I tried `npm install --save bcrypt` - same error.

I tried installing from package.json same error

I cant get the install not to fail and he error message isn't giving me anything that I understand how to troubleshoot. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstalll your `bcrypt` latests version:

```
npm uninstall bcrypt
```

And install version `3`:

```
npm install bcrypt@^3
```

Make sure to check out the documentation at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Or this image below will be help you, what the `bcrypt` version compatible with the `node` version you use in your machine.

[image]

Comment: That was the first thing i tried. Whether v5 or v3 I get the same error message

Comment: Try to install without `^`, sometimes you will get some error if use `^`. Just do this: `npm install bcrypt@3`.

Comment: Or you can look at the documentation, `bcrypt` team recommended this version `npm i bcrypt@3.0.4-napi` if you want to use version `3`

Comment: when i attempted my initial install i didnt use ^ but I just tried it right now and it didnt change the outcome. npm install bcrypt@3 and bcrypt@^3 same result

Comment: If my answer doesn't solve your question, then give downvote to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the `sh` executable cannot be found, which is very strange. The thing that jumps out at me is that you are running `npm` as root. Does it work if you run it as an unprivileged user instead?

Given your operating system/Node.js/npm combination, the `bcyrpt` installation process should be able to download a prebuilt binary, I would think.

Regardless, make sure the directory containing `sh` is in your `PATH` and try again. I was able to replicate your error by removing `/bin` from my `PATH` (because that's where `sh` is on my system and probably yours too).

Comment: I was able to find the issue. It was the PATH not being set. Nodejs  was instaled though cpanel and the variable was not set.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was here: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

I had to set the variable in the /.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/
```

After running command and updating in /.bashrc I was able to install bcrypt 5.0.0